# Use alias for Enum

Tags: kotlin, enums

I want to be able to use a type alias for an Enum `Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` in my code. I'm declaring a lot of them in a matrix and due to the nature of the matrix it can't be done using loops.
I also can't use `var e = Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` since each of them need to be independent values.

I tried `typealias e = Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` but it gives me the error that  `Use of enum entry names as types is not allowed, use enum type instead`

Comment: The error message says it: Foofoofoofoo is a type, but Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR is not. So you cannot typealias the latter.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you share the code? Declaring a typealias for a value (and not a type) is a weird thing to want to do, so I suspect this is an XY problem.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "can't use var e = `Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` since each of them need to be independent values."? Only one instance of `Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` exists at any point—what exactly breaks if you use this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a few comments have explained, you can't typealias `Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` because `Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` is a value, not a type. However, it looks like what you want could be solved with a **static import**:

```kotlin
package test

import test.Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR

enum class Foofoofoofoo {
    BARBARBARBAR
}

val myFooFoos = listOf(BARBARBARBAR, BARBARBARBAR, BARBARBARBAR)
```

(Replace `test` with the package `Foofoofoofoo` is declared in).

In this example, the line `import test.Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` allows you to use the name `BARBARBARBAR` without full qualification. If `BARBARBARBAR` is still too long, you could even use an **import alias**:

```kotlin
package test

import test.Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR as e

enum class Foofoofoofoo {
    BARBARBARBAR
}

val myFooFoos = listOf(e, e, e)
```

Note that here we changed `import test.Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR` to `import test.Foofoofoofoo.BARBARBARBAR as e`, shortening the name further.